# Month Calendar vb.net 6:2 dimensions

Tags: vb.net, calendar

I have a Month Calendar in my vb.net project and i make it 6 by 2 in order to view all months of the current year.My problem is that it starts from the month that we are currently now and moving forward  to months of next year.I want always to start from 1 january and end on 31 of december.How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [MonthCalendar.SetDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.setdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
myMonthCalendar.SetDate(Convert.ToDateTime("01 jan 2015"))
```

Comment: You are welcome! If an answer helps, consider please to mark it as "resolved"

Comment: ok i will . Do you know some way in order for the boldeddates that i choose to have a different kind of characteristic instead of bold.changing color or have a border around date ? @ duDe

Comment: I would ask this question as a separate one as it has no reference to the old one.